# How to create a nested List of derived classes

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm writing an application to deal with WMI objects. I have a `Computer` class with a `List<Component>` property, being `Component` an abtract base class from which come all the derived classes such as `Monitor`, `ComputerUnit`, `Printer` and so on.

Considering the great variety of WMI objects I've decided to use custom .NET generics for the first time (I'm a beginner) and this was the code - just the relevant lines:

```
public class Computer
{
    public List<Component> ListOfComponents { get; set; }
}

public class Component
{ 
    public NameSpaceBase[] WMI_ClassArray { get; set; }
}

public class Monitor : Component
{ }

public class ComputerUnit : Component
{ }

public static void Main()
{
    Computer computer = new Computer(hostName);

    Monitor monitor = computer.Get<Monitor>(new NameSpaceBase[] {
                                                new WMI_Monitor() });

    ComputerUnit computerUnit = computer.Get<ComputerUnit>(
                                    new NameSpaceBase[] {
                                        new WMI_Bios(),
                                        new WMI_ComputerSystem() });

    computer.ListOfComponents.Add(monitor);
    computer.ListOfComponents.Add(computerUnit);
}
```

It was working fine until I realized I wanted to treat every component as a List itself, because I needed to have multiple monitors and/or other multiple devices separated, so I changed my properties and methods accordingly:

```
public class Computer
{
    public List<List<Component>> ListOfComponents { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Computer computer = new Computer(hostName);

    List<Monitor> monitor = computer.Get<Monitor>(new NameSpaceBase[] {
                                                new WMI_Monitor() });

    List<ComputerUnit> computerUnit = computer.Get<ComputerUnit>(
                                new NameSpaceBase[] {
                                    new WMI_Bios(),
                                    new WMI_ComputerSystem() });

    computer.ListOfComponents.Add(monitor);
    computer.ListOfComponents.Add(computerUnit);
}
```

but now I'm given `error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Machine.Components.Monitor>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Machine.Components.Component>'` at the last two lines.

I can't understand where the error stands, because if I comment the last two lines I can see that the List and List objects are correctly created, of the right type and populated with the intended data.

Bottom line of the story: I don't understand why can't I add a `List<Monitor>` object to a `List<List<Component>>`, while I **can** add a `Monitor` object to a `List<Component>`.

Comment: This has to do with covariance, but I'm not sure why it won't work since List<T> is covariant.

Comment: @rory.ap because covariance is related to  the interface and delegate only

Comment: @rory.ap, covariance in classes isn't supported

Comment: Ahh that's it.  Right.  So change the type of `Computer.ListOfComponents` from `List<Component>` to `IList<Component>`.

Comment: I guess a simple IList<List<Component>> would solve the issue then?

Comment: No, you need to change the concrete classes to interface like `List<IComponent>` and `List<IMonitor>`

Comment: Another solution would be if you use the Component class and add a (Child)Components property as ```List<Component>```. Also see [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically answer your question:

> I don't understand why can't I add a List<Monitor> object to a
>   List<List<Component>>, while I can add a Monitor object to a
>   List<Component>.

This is the same as asking why you can't assign `List<Derived>` to a `List<Base>` where `Derived : Base`.

Some languages *do* allow this, but C# doesn't. Let's examine why.

Consider these classes:

```
class Animal
{
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public void Meow() {}
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public void Bark() { }
}
```

Now suppose you have a list of dogs:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog> {new Dog()};
```

You are NOT allowed to do the following:

```
List<Animal> animals = dogs;  // Not allowed - let's pretend it is!
```

Ok let's pretend that the above line compiles. After it's executed, the `animals` list will be a reference to `dogs`, which is a `List<Dog>`. Remember this important fact!

Now let's do the following:

```
animals.Add(new Cat());
```

Seem ok right? Nope. We've just added a `Cat` to `dogs`, which now contains two elements; a `Cat` and a `Dog`.

Now what happens if we do `dogs[1].Bark();`?

The answer is that the program would blow up at runtime because cats can't bark! Of course, this can't actually happen because you're not allowed to do `List<Animal> animals = dogs;`.

---

**A possible solution?**

There's an [`IReadOnlyList<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can use instead of `IList<T>`:

```
IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals = dogs; // Compiles OK.
```

This is allowed because it is declared like so:

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>, 
IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

The [`out T`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) specifies that the interface is [*covariant*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index).

Because `IReadOnlyList` does not allow modification, it is possible for it to support covariance.

Comment: Changed to List<IReadOnlyList<Component>> and runs smoothly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around your requirement of a List of Lists is to simply use List and then filter whenever you need all components of a specific type.

```
monitors = computer.ListOfComponents.OfType<Monitor>();
```

Such a design also makes it easier to modify this collection, as you don't have to deal with the case of adding a component of a specific type for the first time, in which case you would need to create and add the sublist too.

Answer (score -2):

```
computer.ListOfComponents.Add(monitor.Cast<Component>().ToList());
computer.ListOfComponents.Add(computerUnitCast<Component>().ToList());
```

Comment: Whether it works or not, you should include some context/explanation for this.

Comment: It works, actually. I haven't downvoted, but I think your solution simply offers a shortcut on a design flaw. But works!